# Rendering with background, but saving with alpha?

Tags: rendering, transparency, saving

Excuse me for my language)
I want to setup render view like V-Ray Framebufer in 3Ds Max:
 I'd like to render object and see it on a background image. But it still needs to have alpha-transparency, so if I'll save it to png there will be only the object with no background.

Here is what I'd like to see:

[image: Here is what I'd like to see:]

And here is what I'd like to save (in alpha chanel):

[image: And here is what I'd like to save:]

Comment: If your background is an actual geometry you can do that easily by separating foreground and background into different scene layers, then render them to two separate render layers.

Comment: Thank you for help! But I doubt it helps me - I'll try to describe more accurate.
 How does it work in VRay: 
1. I set matte parameter ON and alpha -1 to my background object (BG)
2. Then I render image
3. I see my foreground objects (FG) are on the BG.
4. I save image to PNG.
5. I open image in Photoshop or Image Viewer and see only FG

Answer (score 1):

This would be a good place to use the compositor:

[image]

Have a renderlayer of your object on a transparent background, and another renderlayer with just the background. Let the transparent background render remain connected to the "Composite" output node, and mix the two renderlayers for the "Viewer" output node so you can see it on the background while in blender.

If you want to save time on rendering, and your background doesn't change, you can render the background, save it as a texture, then mix using that texture instead of an additional renderlayer.

Comment: Thank you! Could I somehow setup nodes to see it on UI/Image Editor screen? (and to save it with F3 on UI/Image Editor at once?)